# Wp api for flutter

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter, api, converters

I am trying to use the wordpress api, but it throws me an error when entering the url.
Error: The argument type "String" can't be assigned to the parameter type Uri

Could someone explain the error to me and tell me how the code should look? Thanks

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


Future<List> blog() async {
  final response = await http.get(('https://bauk.blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed': {"Accept": "application/json"}));
  var convertirajson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return convertirajson;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The argument type "String" can't be assigned to the parameter type Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the url before passing it to http.get()

For that declare your url variable like this:

`var url = Uri.parse('https://bauk.blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed');`

And then pass it to http.get() like this

`http.get((url: {...} ));`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved my question

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the error line in the question as well. It would help others facing this same problem when they look up for this error.

Comment: Ready. I have edited the question